# Django Template - If item == return field from model object

Tags: python, django

Django 1.10, python 3.5

Hi All!

I have a model, in models.py called "Building_type":

```
class Building_type(models.Model):
    buildingType = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.buildingType
```

and a list of buildings that is sent to the django HTML template, called "buildingList", that looks like so:

```
[
 {'name': 'building1', 'type': <Building_type: Blacksmith>},
 {'name': 'building2', 'type': <Building_type: Inn>},
 {'name': 'building3', 'type': <Building_type: Chemist>},
]
```

I would like to do this:

```
{% for building in buildingList %}
    {% if building.type == "Inn" %}
        <p> this is an Inn </p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However the IF statement never completes as true.
I have tried the following, all have failed:

```
{% if building.type == building.type.Inn %}
{% if building.type == Inn %}
{% if building.type == "Inn" %}
```

---

If it helps, the following correctly returns "Blacksmith", "Inn", and "Chemist" to HTML:

```
{% for building in buildingList %}
    {% if building.type %}
        {{building.type}}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Many thanks if you all can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i'm following this correctly shouldn't this work?

`{% if building.type.buildingType == "Inn" %}`

as type is an instance of a Building_type model which in turn has a field of buildingType so accessing that is `type.buildingType`

Comment: That's great glad it worked, please accept the answer if you can.